# Category template not displaying all post formats

Tags: templates, post-formats

When I visit a category page that lists all posts in that category, the divs that are to hold the content are empty.  The template is clearly only set to display the standard post format, but none of the others (video, audio, quote, gallery, link).

How do I fix this?

Below is the contents of my category template:

```
<?php
    get_header();
    if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;
        get_template_part( 'includes/navigation', 'index' );
    else:
        get_template_part( 'includes/no-results', 'index' );
    endif;
    get_footer();
?>
```

I also have template-part files for all the post formats, i.e. content-gallery.php

Comment: Help please! Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the codex on get_template_part and get_post_format will help you a lot here.

It's hard to say for sure without knowing what files are in your theme but `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` is essentially saying use the template named content-*format*.php, where *format* is one of image, video, gallery etc. One of a few things is happening:

Either your theme doesn't contain these templates at all, although you should still see posts in the fallback single.php format if that were the case. Still worth checking if they exist as no point using `get_post_format()`if they don't.

Or those templates are in a sub directory down form your category template in which case you'd need the format `get_template_part( 'subfolder/content', get_post_format() );`

Or your posts all have the default/standard format in which case `get_post_format()` will return false. If this is the case then you could remove `get_post_format()` and use just `get_template_part( 'content' );` where all posts will use the default content template part. Alternatively you can assign a value to the false response:

```
get_header();
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $format = get_post_format();
    if ( false === $format ) {
    $format = 'standard';
                            }
        get_template_part( 'content', $format );
    endwhile;
    get_template_part( 'includes/navigation', 'index' );
else:
    get_template_part( 'includes/no-results', 'index' );
endif;
get_footer();
```

Here you'd need to insure you added a content-standard.php alongside the other format template parts.